# when strdup function fails?

Tags: c, string, strdup

i have following code  which use  strdup function

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char source[] = "The Source String ";

int main()
{
  char *dest;
  if ((dest = _strdup(source)) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, " Error allocation memory. ");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("The destination = %s\n", dest);
  return 0;
}
```

it  successfully says The Source String,but i am interesting in which situation it fails and how good it is usage of it in daily problems?i know that strdup it is determined by

```
char *strdup (const char *s)
{
    char *d = malloc (strlen (s) + 1);   // Space for length plus nul
    if (d == NULL) return NULL;          // No memory
    strcpy (d,s);                        // Copy the characters
    return d;                            // Return the new string
}
```

if our string is not NULL,is there any chance of failing  strdup function?

Comment: Be careful you use `_strdup` instead of `strdup` and I'm not sure you know why.

Comment: compiler  gave me warning  about it

Comment: @dato: The compiler gave you a warning about `_strdup`, or about `strdup`?  The `strdup` function is not defined by the C standard.  It is defined by POSIX.  You might need to do something to make your compiler recognize it, like `#define`ing some symbol.  Using `_strdup` rather than `strdup` is not a good solution.

Comment: Warning 1 warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See online help for details. c:\documents and settings\student\my documents\visual studio 2008\projects\strdup_function\strdup_function\strdup_function.cpp 8 strdup_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if `malloc` fails to allocate memory and returns `NULL`.

This could reasonably happen when you're trying to duplicate a very large string, or if your address space is very fragmented and nearly full (so taht `malloc` can't find a contiguous block of memory to allocate, or in embedded systems where not much memory is available.

Answer (score 1):

The chance of `strdup` failing is determined by the chance of `malloc` failing. On modern operating systems with virtual memory, a `malloc` failure is a very rare thing. The OS may have even killed your entire process before the system gets so low on memory that `malloc` has to return `NULL`.

Comment: Or worse, the OS may [kill some *other* process](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer).

Answer (score 1):

It's not unheard of to run out of memory, if there is a memory leak.
So it's not a bad idea to check for null, print out error message, and maybe even exit at that point.
Note that things like 'printf' won't work (or may not work, but in my experience don't work) if you run out of memory.  So you gotta use low-level 'write' or such, and file descriptor you're using (if you're writing to log file), should already be opened.